# How to set corner radius for a container in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have used Listbox in my application. I want to set corner radius for `listbox` items without using resources. I have set `borderthickness`, border brush and background using `itemsContainer` settings but there is no corner radius property there. By using resources then the only `cornerradius` property is accessed.

How can I achieve this without using resources?

I am new to .Net developing, so please give any suggestion to fix this,

```
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>              
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,15,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>                    
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the `CornerRadius` of most of the containers. However you can set the `CornerRadius` of a `Border` and then set any container's `OpacityMask` to this `Border`.

Here is how you do it:

```
<Grid>
    <Border x:Name="Container" Height="25" Background="White" CornerRadius="8"/>
    <ListBox>

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Container}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>

        <ListBoxItem x:Name="Item1" Height="25" Content="Item #1"/>

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

If you really want to do the same thing without resources:

```
<Grid>
    <Border x:Name="Container" Height="25" Background="White" CornerRadius="8"/>
    <ListBox>

        <ListBoxItem x:Name="Item1" Height="25" Content="Item #1" Background="LightGreen">
            <ListBoxItem.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Container}"/>
            </ListBoxItem.OpacityMask>
        </ListBoxItem>

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Here you might want to bind heights to same value.

One important thing to note is that if you don't give `Border` background color, it will be trasparent therefore the item you set opacity mask of will be invisible. The color of `Border`'s `BackgroundColor` is irrelevant. But make sure there is an item covering that border, it is `ListBox` in this case.